# Progress 4gl :Counting Records?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am new to progress 4gl. i have one query where I have to count number of sales order for particular customer.

for eg: I have table as so_mstr and so_cust is my customer name field and so_nbr is my sale order number field.

in SQL I tried like this ,

```
select so_cust,count(distinct so_nbr) from so_mstr group by so_cust.
```

pls help me in progress.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule #1 -- Progress is **NOT** SQL.  Nothing but pain and agony lies down the path of attempting to use SQL within the 4gl.

The 4gl does support some limited SQL-89 syntax such as:

```
select count(*) from customer.
```

but that was put in the product a very long time ago and is really just to satisfy checklist oriented product evaluations from the early 90s.  It is sometimes useful for a quick hack in an ad-hoc query but not for serious use.  IOW "it makes a good demo".  Real SQL is supported via the SQL-92 interface.  Which is a separate product from the 4gl and generally used to support reporting tools such as Crystal Reports or whatever.

If there is one "so_mstr" per order and you need to know the number of orders for every customer then the simple 4gl way to count those records is:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

for each so_mstr no-lock where so_mstr.so_domain = "xxx" break by so_mstr.so_cust:
  i = i + 1.
  if last-of( so_mstr.so_cust ) then
    do:
      display so_mstr.so_cust i.
      i = 0.
    end.
end.
```

Your code is trying to do something with "distinct" so my assumption about uniqueness of sales order numbers per customer might be faulty (but that seems like a really bad design on someones part).

You could do more complicated things with the FOR EACH involving break groups and automatic counting functions but those options are not any faster and they are, IMHO, much less readable.  Especially for someone who is just getting started with the 4gl.

(For performance you can also use "field lists" but that really only matters if the connection is over a WAN rather than via shared memory and it complicates the syntax.  Which I did not want to do for a simple example.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Tom. But I want to print for all customers.

Comment: I tried this, for each so_mstr where so_domain="xxx" break by so_cust.
       display so_cust  so_nbr(count by so_cust).
end.

Comment: It is an example -- you need to ask for what you actually want if you want your actual problem solved.  And disclose the full schema and relationships between the tables.  The key is to get the proper WHERE clause.

Comment: I would not attempt to use "count" or any of the other aggregate keywords.  They make your code unreadable and they are very tricky to get right.  Just create a variable.  It is easier and works better.

Comment: "I would not attempt use count" ... another matter on which I am in total agreement with TomB! Whenever I try to use these things, I always end up rewriting it "the old fashioned way" eventually.

Comment: "my assumption about uniqueness of sales order numbers per customer might be faulty", no, you're correct, `so_nbr` (sales order number) is unique in MFG and the `distinct` is redundant in the OP. This could have somewhat been confused with the `ih_nbr` (invoice sales order number) which is not unique but corresponds to `so_nbr`, this is because an order can be split into more than one invoice. IMHO ABL(4GL) is a terrible environment with such missing aggregates where a simple `@c = select count(*)` could have being significantly vertically and horizontally concise.